# Declaring Func<in T, out Result> dynamically

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, predicate, anonymous-methods

Consider this:

```
var propertyinfo = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(sortExpressionStr);
Type orderType = propertyinfo.PropertyType;
```

now I want to declare

```
Func<int,orderType>
```

I know its not possible directly since `ordertype` is at runtime but is there is any workaround ?

this is exactly what I want to do :

```
var propertyinfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortExpressionStr);
Type orderType = propertyinfo.PropertyType;

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var sortExpression = (Expression.Lambda<Func<T, orderType>>
   (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortExpressionStr), typeof(orderType)), param));
```

all this because I want to convert:

```
Expression<Func<T,object>> to Expression<Func<T,orderType>>
```

or if its not possible then I want to create it from the first place with the right type , the case is as following:

I'm inside a method which have a `type(Customer)` and a property name of that type I want to order by it , I want to create a sort expression tree to pass it to `Orderby` (here).

Comment: You can't declare at compile-time that `sortExpression` is of type `Expression<Func<T,orderType>>`, because `orderType` is not known at compile-time but only at run-time. How do you expect to use your lambda expression once compiled?

Comment: ok forget about the sortexpression then , is there is any possible way of orderby using a string of propertyname ?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: This seems to be the same question [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819631/dictionary-of-linq-expression/3819963#3819963 "answered here") This approach stays type-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
linqClass.OrderBy(GetSortExpression(sortstr));


public static Expression<Func<T,object>> GetSortExpression<T>(string sortExpressionStr)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Property(param, sortExpressionStr), param);
        return sortExpression;
    }
```

this worked my problem was i used to pass extra parameter Typeof(Object) and orderby used to tell me it cant sort by Object type. thanks all

thanks dtb i will check if your answer work too and i will accept it if it works if not i will accept thsi one.

Comment: This is not working for me.
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
/*fill list*/
when i call like this : list.OrderBy(GetSortExpression("MyColName"))

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using an open generic type definition, and then making the specific type from that:

```
typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), orderType);
```

However, what you're trying to do (calling `Lambda<TDelegate>`) is not directly possible. You must call `Lambda` without a type parameter:

```
var propertyinfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortExpressionStr);
Type orderType = propertyinfo.PropertyType;

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortExpressionStr),
                           orderType), 
        param));
```

This will create the proper `Func<,>` for you behind the scenes. If you want to compile the expression and use the delegate, you can only do this dynamically with

```
sortExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(param);
```

If you want to call the `OrderBy` extension method on `Queryable`, things get a little more complicated:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortExpressionStr);
Type orderType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

// first find the OrderBy method with no types specified
MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
  .Where(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
  .Single();
// then make the right version by supplying the right types
MethodInfo concreteMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), orderType);

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

// the key selector for the OrderBy method
Expression orderBy =
    Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Property(orderParam, propertyInfo),
        orderParam);

// how to use:
var sequence = new T[0].AsQueryable(); // sample IQueryable

// because no types are known in advance, we need to call Invoke 
// through relection here
IQueryable result = (IQueryable) concreteMethod.Invoke(
                                   null, // = static
                                   new object[] { sequence, orderBy });
```

Comment: no buddy , typeof(orderType) wouldnt compile , i tried that already

Comment: typeof(orderType) is not logical , since your trying to typeof is in compile time and ordertype only in runtime i guess

Comment: Just curious: Why does one need to Expression.Convert the property which has type `orderType` to type `orderType`?

Comment: @dtb when your making dynamic sort and you dont know which property is going to be passed! and what type of it , when its passed to you as a string

Comment: sadly that wont work too Ruben because then i wont be able to use the return of DynamicInvoke with linqClass.OrderBy(here);

Comment: cause the return of DynamicInvoke is an object which cant inferred its type.

Comment: You won't call `DynamicInvoke`, that will happen inside `Enumerable.OrderBy`.  But you'll have to call `Enumerable.OrderBy` dynamically as well since you don't know what its generic type arguments are until runtime either.

Comment: @Stacker: But why do you need to **convert** it? It's already of the right type, no?

Comment: @dtb, i dont need to convert it, i was thinking of that as a possible solution but i need to create it from the first place using the right type but i couldnt, like i said im inside a method which have a type(Customer) and a property name of the time i want to orderby i want to create a sort expression tree to pass it to Orderby(here)

Comment: +1, I absolutely **love** answers like this one. The code is beautiful and stuff like this often comes in handy when playing with generics via reflection.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Type.MakeGenericType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx):

```
Type result = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), orderType);
```

---

This should work:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(
    IQueryable<T> q, string sortfield, bool ascending)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var x = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(p, sortfield), p);

    return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(
               Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
                               ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
                               new Type[] { q.ElementType, x.Body.Type },
                               q.Expression,
                               x));
}
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646703/creating-a-sort-function-for-a-generic-list/2646823#2646823).

Comment: im not sure if this meets my case , and im not sure how to test it , any way i fixed the problem thanks any way dtb for your time and efforts.

Comment: @Stacker: So, how did you fix the problem? Others might stumble upon your question and be having the same problem.

Comment: i already posted the solution and posted what was wrong in my code . thank u buddy

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Dynamic Linq, a part of the Visual Studio sample code.

[image: Example code using Dynamic Linq]

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: yes this would work but i didnt want to include dynamic linq dll

Comment: It's distributed as a source file, not an assembly. You can compile it into your assembly to avoid any extra references. Take a look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Samples\1033\CSharpSamples.zip, and the compressed file LinqSamples\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs

Answer (score 1):

See if my solution dynamic enough.

```
public class Product
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Product> products = (from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                          select new Product { ID = i, Name = "product " + i, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i) }).ToList();  //the test case

    const string SortBy = "Date";  // to test you can change to "ID"/"Name"

    Type sortType = typeof(Product).GetProperty(SortBy).PropertyType;     // DateTime
    ParameterExpression sortParamExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");    // {p}
    Expression sortBodyExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(sortParamExp, SortBy);   // {p.DateTime}
    LambdaExpression sortExp = Expression.Lambda(sortBodyExp, sortParamExp);   //   {p=>p.DateTime}
    var OrderByMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.Equals("OrderBy") && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).FirstOrDefault().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Product), sortType);
    var result = OrderByMethod.Invoke(products, new object[] { products, sortExp.Compile() });
}
```

Base on above, it's not difficult to change `Product` to `T` to make it generic.

Comment: Yes i could use that if im using linq to enumrable but not linq to sql as this would lead to getting the records the sort so if your onlyb taking first 10 and skiping its going to make trouble as u need to make sort in sql using orderby method while ur retivimg the records !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Type` associated with `Func<int,orderType>` in case you wanted to e.g. pass it into [CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx).

But what are you ultimately wanting to do with it?  There may be a more straightforward approach.