# Order a List by a arbitrary sort expression?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Question:

I have a generic list, like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Question> myquestions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Question>();
```

And I have a paging example, using a LINQ table acquried from database, doing this for paging:

```
var questions = context.Questions
    .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);
```

Right now, for paging my populated from code list, I have:

```
var questionss = myquestions
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);
```

And what I want is being able to order "myquestions" by a string as in the above example.
Is that possible?

Comment: Can you give examples of what sidx and sord would look like? Where do you get sidx and sord from. That is how do these change for every record?

Comment: example: sidx = "Id", sord = "ASC"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bahaha, now I'm gonna cry:

Trying to implement dtb's solution, I saw the problem:

```
OrderByField<T>(IQueryable<T> q,
```

Returns IQueryable while inputting IQueryable... lol bs.
So, the real question is how to convert List to be iQueryable.

Which, in fact is dead simple:

```
var list = new List<T>(); 
var queryable = list.AsQueryable();
```

then

```
queryable.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord);
```

So the final solution is as trivial as:

```
myquestions.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Which also means Linq.Table implements IQueryable, which makes sense IMHO.

**Edit: 

Note:** This requires reference to: Dynamic.dll (not System.Dynamic.dll)
as well as

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

If you don't reference Dynamic.dll, or don't declare the using directive, you'll get an error on AsQueryable().

Comment: This is the best answer by miles. If you don't have System.Linq.Dynamic, just use nuget to get it.

Answer (score 3):

You can chain the extension methods in separate statements thanks to the lazy execution, which means that you can add different sorting depending on a condition:

```
IOrderedQueryable<Question> sorted;
switch (sort) {
  case "Id":  sorted = myquestions.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
  case "Name": sorted = myquestions.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
  case "Size": sorted = myquestions.OrderBy(x => x.Size);
  case "Id Desc":  sorted = myquestions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
  case "Name Desc": sorted = myquestions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
  case "Size Desc": sorted = myquestions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Size);
  default: throw new NotImplementedException();
}
var questions = sorted.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

You can even add a secondary sorting (or as many as you like, after the first they are all the same):

```
IOrderedQueryable<Question> sorted;
switch (sort) {
  case "Id":  sorted = myquestions.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
  case "Name": sorted = myquestions.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
  case "Size": sorted = myquestions.OrderBy(x => x.Size);
  case "Id Desc":  sorted = myquestions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
  case "Name Desc": sorted = myquestions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
  case "Size Desc": sorted = myquestions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Size);
  default: throw new NotImplementedException();
}
switch (sort2) {
  case "Id":  sorted = sorted.ThenBy(x => x.Id);
  case "Name": sorted = sorted.ThenBy(x => x.Name);
  case "Size": sorted = sorted.ThenBy(x => x.Size);
  case "Id Desc":  sorted = sorted.ThenByDescending(x => x.Id);
  case "Name Desc": sorted = sorted.ThenByDescending(x => x.Name);
  case "Size Desc": sorted = sorted.ThenByDescending(x => x.Size);
}
var questions = sorted.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752305/declaring-funcin-t-out-result-dynamically/3753377#3753377) on how to build a custom `OrderBy` predicate using `Expression` from a given `String`.

Comment: I like it, but it still needs to be extended by using list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id) when sortd is DESC. The problem is I don't quite understand it, YET (but I get the idea)...

Comment: Thanks, the answer by dtb in your link is perfect.

Comment: @Quandary: Well that's easy to implement in this solution, you don't need to modify too much. But the more dynamic, the more work(probably the slower). Follow @JSkeet's solution if you don't want it *too dynamic*.

Comment: @Quandary: LOL I don't know I should be happy or sad :(

Comment: Hmm, sad! Sad that I didn't realize the problem in those 10 seconds. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a dictionary from each possible ordering string to an appropriate delegate. For example:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<Question>, IEnumerable<Question>> orderings =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<Question>, IEnumerable<Question>>()
{
    { "Id",  questions => questions.OrderBy(x => x.Id) },
    { "Title",  questions => questions.OrderBy(x => x.Title) },
    { "Answer",  questions => questions.OrderBy(x => x.Answer) },
    { "Id Desc",  questions => questions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id) },
    { "Title Desc",  questions => questions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title) },
    { "Answer Desc",  questions => questions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Answer) },
};
```

Then you can find that mapping at execution time, and apply the function.

Comment: I get the idea, but it's gonna create an awful lot of typing, plus it will be a 2d dictionary, because it also needs sort order ASC|DESC. Automatizing this would probably require reflection.

Comment: @Quandary: You could always sort ascending and use `Reverse` if you want a descending list. I'd guess either the Linq query optimizer or the SQL server are smart enough to optimize that away and do a descending sort instead.

Comment: I'll remember that if I need very custom search order.

Comment: @JonSkeet, does this still hold for you?

Comment: @Rod: What in particular?

Comment: Your dictionary answer. I'm trying to use the dynamic sortExpression string with linq.

Comment: @Rod: Well yes, as noted on the answer you accepted, you weren't doing anything with the result.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just wondering if there was another concise way to do it. No biggie.

Comment: @Rod: It would have been helpful if you'd said that to start with. This is still the way I would personally do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). IIRC it was a sample that shipped with VS2008, I'm not 100% sure if it's still included in VS2010.