# Entity Framework , List and Lambda

Tags: list, lambda, ef-code-first

im working with EF codefirst and i need to sort the list of entries, i tried but could not find how to solve this task:

Lets say we have expression

```
thelist.orderby(p=> p.Name)
```

Question is : 
**How to pass string instead of "p.Name" in case if i want to order list by p.Age for example**

Because there are like 20 or more options to sort so im trying to shrink the code

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx

is it the right way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752305/declaring-funcin-t-out-result-dynamically/3753377#3753377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Dynamic LINQ ([NuGet source](http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicQuery)), include `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` with your namespaces, and you'll be able to call:

```
thelist.OrderBy("Name");
thelist.OrderByDescending(someStringParameter);
```

etc.